How to extrude along normals in Blender 4.2?
How to extrude along normals in Blender 4.2?
I can't do it like the picture

this is mine


That’s not even the same tool…

Apply the scale to your object in Object mode (Ctrl-A > Scale) first then Alt-E > Extrude Faces along Normals with the faces you want to extrude selected in Edit mode.

so, do you want extrude the edges straight accroding the normal like in the first picture?

If i understand your question, you can use Mesh Tools add-on its built-in add-ons
you can install through extension
and then in N Panel > Edit > Edge Tools select Offset Edges



Thanks Bro! I Love You
